# jQuery extended function preserve chaining based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a jquery build it function which will allow me to change maxHeight or retrieve maxHeight from an element or a set of elements.

setting a maxHeight by : `$('.element-class').maxHeight(500);` works great.
However when I dont pass a parameter in maxHeight() I'd like to return the element's height and not preserve jquery chainability:

Source:

```
(function($) {

    // jQuery plugin definition
    $.fn.maxHeight = function() {

        var params = arguments;
        var $this = this;
        console.log(params);
        this.each(function() {

            var $t = $(this);

            if (params.length > 0 ) {
                if (params[0] == 'none'){
                    $t.get(0).style.maxHeight = 'none';
                } else {
                    $t.get(0).style.maxHeight = params[0] + 'px';
                }
                return $t;
            } else {
                var h = (($t.get(0).style.maxHeight && $t.get(0).style.maxHeight != '') ? parseInt($t.get(0).style.maxHeight) : 0);
                console.log(h);
                return h;
            }

        });

        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to make a callback function, didn't have time to test it but try this:

```
(function($) {

    // jQuery plugin definition
    $.fn.maxHeight = function(a, callback) {

        var $this = this;
        this.each(function() {

            var $t = $(this);

            if (!a) {
                    $t.get(0).style.maxHeight = 'none';
                } else {
                    $t.get(0).style.maxHeight = a + 'px';
                }
                callback($t);
            } else {
                var h = (($t.get(0).style.maxHeight && $t.get(0).style.maxHeight != '') ? parseInt($t.get(0).style.maxHeight) : 0);
                callback(h);
            }

        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

and then do something like this:

```
$('.element-class').maxHeight(500 , function(result){


// use your result or not

// Want to chain 
return result;

});
```

Comment: The if / else isnt quite correct i see, but you solved it i see ;)